# Firestore transactions - How to Add only when key does not exist. Never wish to update

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection where I insert a document. I need to insert a document with a particular key only if no one has already added it before. If key exists and I need to update using transactions - that work great. But here I need to ensure no document with that keys exists and then insert it.  Please do not discuss how to update existing record with firestore transactions - that works great - and that is not my question. My question is how to ensure and CHECK the document does not exist in the collection, and only then ADD it. *And Make sure between my CHECK and ADD - no one grabbed the opportunity and added the document with that key.* In that case I will end up updating the document that was just added by someone. Because seems like firestore transactions do not lock non-existing documents - or do they? What is the solution for this issue?

```
// Checking if document exists - if it does updating some field (not important)
ref := clientdb.Collection("mycollection").Doc("12345")
err = clientdb.RunTransaction(context.Background(), func(ctx context.Context, tx *firestore.Transaction) error {
    doc, err := tx.Get(ref) // tx.Get, NOT ref.Get!
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    count1, err := doc.DataAt("querycount")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return tx.Set(ref, map[string]interface{}{
        "querycount": count1.(int64) + 1,
    }, firestore.MergeAll)
})
 /* Important part is here */
/* If someone inserts the document with same key here, I will end up updating it below */
/* I wish to guarantee no one inserts document with that key "12345" */
/* THE TIME HERE is crucial, no one should be able to add the key here (say a different session/thread that preempted my OS thread at this location or if firestore inserted someone else document using different session)  */ 

if err != nil {
        // Inserting document here - do not wish to update if someone already inserted after the above check        
        _, err = clientdb.Collection("mycollection").Doc("12345").Set(context.Background(), map[string]interface{}{ 
        "field1": field1,
        "querycount": 0,
        })

}
```

How to ensure, I am not updating someone else's document (or my own document that was added just microseconds ago with multiple button clicks, or two people clicked at the same time to add and one of them grabbed it and added - right between the check and the actual insert/add command of the second person.) More important I need to add only if no one has already added. Do not wish to touch/update document someone else added (or touch my own document if I added it before - say multiple button clicks and sending the request again and again). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [DocumentRef.Create](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#DocumentRef.Create) to create a new document.  The Create method fails if a document with the same id exists.

See also [Transaction.Create](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#Transaction.Create) and [WriteBatch.Create](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#WriteBatch.Create).

Use [CollectionRef.NewDoc](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#CollectionRef.NewDoc) to create a unique document id.

Comment: Firestore "Create" worked perfectly - it fails on duplicate key, and I try again few times with another id in a loop. Thank you!

Comment: @Pat Call [CollectionRef.NewDoc](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#CollectionRef.NewDoc) to create a unique document  id instead of probing for a unique id with a counter.

Comment: Hi, my keys need to be random number between 1000000000 and 9999999999, so using sum of unix time and number pary of the ip address of the user for the seed of the random number. There was never a collusion with million of inserts. But just in case, I am looping through 10 times in case. In the 11th time, I am asking the user to try later again. the querycount you see in my example -it never exceeded 0. But to get a good night sleep, I added the logic I presented above. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your `doc` variable is a [DocumentSnapshot](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#DocumentSnapshot).  You can use its [Exists()](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#DocumentSnapshot.Exists) method to check if the document exists, and use that to decide what to do in your transaction as a result.

Comment: Thank you Doug. What if some other firestore process preempts between my check Exists() command and actual Add/Insert. I am not locking anything using firestore transactions because the document does not even exists.

Comment: The whole point of transactions is that they act atomically and are retried in the face of contention from other clients.  You won't have a problem if you implement the transaction correctly.

Comment: Thank you. The document does not exists yet, I am trying to be the first person to insert it. What should the transaction lock if the document does not exists yet. Unlike SQL databases where it would fail with unique constraint violation, but here it quietly updates the transaction if it exists.

Comment: Just check the return value of Exists, and decide in each case if you want the transaction to create the document or not.  There is nothing special to do.

Comment: Doug, Thank you, I am sorry need to clarify. What if I check with Exists() and them I am ready to ADD/Insert. But firestore adds someone else's document at that instance using another session and grabs it (RIGHT in between my Exists() check and actual Insert/Add - chronologically.) 1) I check using Exists() and I am ready to insert 2) Firestore inserts the same key using someone else's session, 3) I Add/Insert, but that document was just added, I do not fail with unique constraint violation, but I end up updating that someone else's document just added by them.

Comment: I am asking because my application will send out 1000s of inserts and co-workers will do the same. The first one should go through - other attempts should fail, but should not update - currently every subsequent attempted insert ends up updating the first one.

Comment: If you don't use set-with-merge as you are now (which effectively acts like an update if the document already exists), then you won't have a problem.  Let the set/create operation fail normally due to the new document already existing.

Comment: And also, the thing to realize about transactions is that when you GET a document inside a transaction, Firestore will lock that document.  When using the backend SDK, that document can not change by another client, and the update will be fully atomic.  When using a frontend SDK, the document will be locked optimistically, and if the document does manage to change, the transaction handler will be retried (and it will now see that the document exists).  The bottom line is that the operation will be atomic in either case, as long as you write your transaction correctly.

Comment: I recommend reviewing the documentation if you haven't already: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions

Comment: I appreciate it Doug. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, It worked with Firestore Create command. Adding it here.

```
current_id_try = "12345"
            ... loop
            _, err := clientdb.Collection("mycollection").Doc(current_id_try).Create(context.Background(), map[string]interface{}{
                 "field1": field1,
                     "querycount": 0,
            })
            if err != nil {
                // Failed to insert, so return to the next iteration of the for loop to try again.
                current_id_try = some_other_value[i]
                continue
            }  ...break on max tries...

            .. end loop
```